# Grass algorithms do not appear in Sextante toolbar of QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, sextante

I was having problems with some sextante algorithms in my QGIS 1.8, something related with wrong "os" name, I found a post in which reccomend to install the 1.9 master version.

I clean uninstalled the QGIS and then I installed the 1.9 version. When I activate the sextante toolbar, the Grass, TauDEM and even the QGIS algorithms doesn't appear in it. I have tried activating them in the configuration of sextante, reinstalling the plugin but the tools still missing.

Any ideas of what is happening?

Comment: Same problem for me, I opened a ticket: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7897

Answer (score 4):

In QGIS 1.9 you can choose between "Simplified interface" and "Advenced interface" under the SEXTANTE toolbox.

Simplified hide all external algorithms, probably this is your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact as you mention I forgot the "Advanced Interface" now I have al the available tools. I was getting crazy because I tried all complex stuff to solve this issue, reinstalling, change version......and the solution was in front of me all the time.....
Regards.